# Java Spring boot Configuration settings for different environment

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using maven with java Spring-boot.

How can efficiently handle configuration  for different environment?
For instance, if I am on staging use this port, if I am on dev, use this port

Currently, I change all the necessary  settings in the application.properties each time I move to a different environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create different application.properties file for different environment. The environment name should be appended to the filename and separated with dash (-). For example,

you can have  `application-dev.properties` for dev environment , you can also have 'application-staging.properties`for staging environment`application-prod.properties` for production environment.

To activate each environment, pass it as a flag when are starting your .jar application for example

`java -jar myapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=staging`

or you can define the active profile inside `application.properties`.

I.e (In the example below , your application will make use of the configuration inside `application-staging.properties` )

```
spring.profiles.active=staging #comment out to switch away from staging
#spring.profiles.active=dev # uncomment to set active profile to dev
#spring.profiles.active=prod # uncomment to set active profile to prod
```

[image: application.properties configuration]

You can now have different settings based on different environment in the custom created files.

For instance the staging environment could be configured to start on port 8888 as shown below
[image: application-staging.properties content]

and  the dev could be configured to start on port 8989

[image: application-dev.properties content]

Comment: This answer is right on.  I'll just point out that Spring will look for  and read the `application-<profile>.properties` file IN ADDITION to the general `application.properties` file. This means you don't have to duplicate any of the properties that are the same for all environments.  Put those in the general file.  Put profile-specific properties in the corresponding per-profile file.  Also note that the profile-specific file overrides what's in the general file.  So you can in effect give properties "default" values in the main file and then selectively override them in the per-profile file.

Comment: According this article:
https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/23/spring-tips-configuration
the correct name is `--spring.profiles.active`. 
And it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Boot, there is a convention of using a *property* file or a *yaml* file, the pattern used for file naming is `application-{env}.[ yaml | properties ]`.

Specifying the env variable can be passed using `spring.profiles.active` property, e.g.

Say you have a Spring config file named `application-test.yaml` then:

> pom.xml

```xml
.
.
<properties>
 
 <spring.profiles.active>${environment}</spring.profiles.active>

</properties>
.
.
```

To use a different environment for each Maven build you'll need to use *Maven profiles*, e.g.

> pom.xml

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>test</id>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>environment</name>
        <value>test</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

This allows you to control the environment from the console:

```bash
$ mvn clean verify -P test
```

A quick search for *Maven profiles* and *Spring profiles* will probably get you what you need for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring @Profile annotation

You can have environment specific property file

Ex: application-prod.properties
application-dev.properties